# Evaluating Glove model by finding linear algebraic structure of words

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-nlp, word-embedding

I have built Glove model on my text corpus using in c application following this implementation https://github.com/stanfordnlp/GloVe/tree/master/src.
I want to find the word embeddings in such a way that

> If A is related to B and C is related to D, then A-C+B should be equal
>   to D. For example, embedding vector arithmetic of
>   "Australia"-"Canberra"+"India" should be equal to the embedding of
>   "New Delhi".

I want to evaluate these embeddings in python.

Answer (score 1):

Evaluation steps for any `A B C D`:

1. Calculate the vector representation of `D'` with `D' = A-C+B`.
2. For all word vector `v` in trained GloV, calculate the cosine similarity of `v` and `D'`.
3. Check if the most similar vector to `D'` is actually intended word `D`.

Such results can be considered as @top1 like evaluation of an information retrieval. You can change the third step to get `@top k`.

Comment: Does maximum vocab count parameter while generating vocabulary file is linked with the word vector dimensions parameter?I am getting error while evalauting as ** Cannot copy array of sequence of 66 to vectors of dimension 100 **